# NSF Guidelines on Postdoc Salary for Grants Hosted by an Institution/PI

Tags: postdocs, salary, nsf

I'm looking for guidelines the NSF *may* have on minimum salary paid to a postdoc under grants to an institution/PI. These are grants that, for example, I would write which then get awarded to me/my host institution, *not* the family of NSF-funded postdoc grants. I have not been successful in finding these guidelines, if they exist, but lack of evidence is not evidence of lacking.

What I did find is that NIH and NSF issued a joint statement to comply with the Fair Labor Standards Act of 2016. NIH says that PDs should be paid a minimum of $50,004 in 2019 (https://grants.nih.gov/grants/guide/notice-files/NOT-OD-19-036.html). But this is not the same as *NSF* saying the same.

In case you're wondering, no, I'm not trying to see how little I can pay my postdocs. Rather, I want to use NSF as a benchmark so I can march to my HR department and get my postdocs paid what they're worth. (As an institution grants we get are from NSF or similar sources, much less so than NIH, which they could more easily dismiss as "Oh, of course it's high. That's for biomed".)

Comment: Just a guess, but it sounds like a general guideline that would apply across agencies.

Comment: Various NSF documents say different things. I've found things ranging from 'the institution sets the salary' (in a FAQ about the FLSA in 2016) to a 2017 Biology Program document saying the stipend is $4500/month ($54k/yr) directly to the fellow for 24 to 36 months.

Comment: NSF funds two different kinds of postdocs. One type are paid directly by NSF; the postdocs submit their own research proposals directly, and the call for submissions lists the stipend.  (I had such a postdoc, from the math directorate.) The other are paid from research grants awarded to faculty PIs; here the stipend is typically specified in the proposal budget by the PI/institution.